# Can't resolve method getActionBar()(Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio..I am getting following error in Android Studio.."Can't resolve method getActionBar()' in the statement actionBar = getActionBar();..Project was running fine in Eclipse..plzz Help me with this error

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;


import com.facebooklogin.R;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Was your project built? or it giving compile error?

Comment: @ABFORCE its showing getActionBar() in red

Comment: Try making your activity to extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` And tell me what happens

Comment: @ABFORCE it says Cannot resolve symbol ActionBarActivity..then when i import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; that error is gone but still shows error "cannot resolve method getActionBar()"

Comment: no other error appears on extending ActionBarActivity..just i have to import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: what about `getSupportActionBar` ?

Comment: it shows incompatible types..then if i change actionBar declaration to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar ; then that error disappears but two other errors appears..one in ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS other in actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
     .setTabListener(this));

Comment: strange problem because I am using this method with `FragmentActivity` in Android Studio without any errors. Sorry any way I have no idea

Comment: can i send u the project on email..maybe u can help me by seeing the code?

Comment: okay, abforce@live.com

Comment: sent on ur email..use Android Studio to check it..thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your target API is below hony must do change these lines:

Create your activity by extending ActionBarActivity.
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

Use (or extend) one of the Theme.AppCompat themes for your activity

I think you confuse API versions, for example you must call getSupportFragmentManager() in low API and getFragmentManager() on above API 11 and you do not need extend FragmentActivity in API 11 and above because it actually have all functions